# Positioning listings in itemize

Tags: listings, positioning

Minimal Example

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\definecolor{captioncolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{stringcolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}

\newcounter{javacounter}
\stepcounter{javacounter}


% Customize captions of listings
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{captioncolor}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    format = listing,
    labelfont = white,
    singlelinecheck = false, % Needed to not increase the counters by twice
    textfont = white
    }
    
% Styles
\lstdefinestyle{Java}{
    basicstyle = \linespread{1.1}\mdseries,
    backgroundcolor =  \color{backgroundcolor},
    breaklines = true,
    commentstyle = \color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle = \color{identifiercolor},  
    keywordstyle = \color{keywordcolor},
    language = Java,
    literate =
        {\_}{}{0\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
        {ä}{{\"a}}1
        {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}1,
    morekeywords = {assert},
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle=\color{numbercolor},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    stringstyle=\color{stringcolor},
    tabsize = 2,
    title = Java~(\thejavacounter):~\lst@@caption\stepcounter{javacounter},
    xleftmargin = 15pt
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World")
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}
\item Itemize test
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World")
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The problem I have here is that the position of the listings should be adjusted in itemize. It should be indented. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Minimal Example:

[image: Example output]

Preferred result:

[image: Preferred result]

Alternative preferred result:

[image: Alternative preferred result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very clear. Do you like to have the following result?

**Edit:** According to new request, it seems that the matter of interest is:

[image]

which is produced by the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{enumitem}  % <--- added

\definecolor{captioncolor}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}
\definecolor{backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{rgb}{0.55, 0.55, 0.55}
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{stringcolor}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}

\newcounter{javacounter}
\stepcounter{javacounter}


% Customize captions of listings
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{captioncolor}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    format = listing,
    labelfont = white,
    singlelinecheck = false, % Needed to not increase the counters by twice
    textfont = white
    }

% Styles
\lstdefinestyle{Java}{
    basicstyle = \linespread{1.1}\mdseries,
    backgroundcolor =  \color{backgroundcolor},
    breaklines = true,
    commentstyle = \color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle = \color{identifiercolor},
    keywordstyle = \color{keywordcolor},
    language = Java,
    literate =
        {\_}{}{0\discretionary{\_}{}{\_}}
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
        {ä}{{\"a}}1
        {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}1,
    morekeywords = {assert},
    numbers = left,
    numbersep = 5pt,
    numberstyle=\color{numbercolor},
    showspaces = false,
    showstringspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    stringstyle=\color{stringcolor},
    tabsize = 2,
    title = Java~(\thejavacounter):~\lst@@caption\stepcounter{javacounter},
    xleftmargin = 15pt
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World")
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=15pt] % <--- changed
\item Itemize test

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = Java]
public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World")
}
\end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second one. The listing position should start where the itemize dot starts.

Comment: @Nyanyan, MWE (Minimal Working Example) for the selected image is added now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to keep the position of the itemize but to adjust the position of the listing? I've added an example.

Comment: @Nyanyan, well, this now different story. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, can I ask u what your first example was again?

Comment: @Nyanyan, oh I delete it and I don't remember, what was o it. Sorry.